# Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output while installing mysqlclient

Tags: python

I am trying to install **mysqlclient** for python, but I always get this error when I try:

```
$ pip3 install mysqlclient
```

[image: error]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looking at the error message, it seems that there is an `OS Error`, and judging by the terminal layout, you're using Linux.

It seems that to install this package on Linux, there are extra instructions to follow, mentioned on [the module's github page](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/):

> You may need to install the Python 3 and MySQL development headers and
> libraries like so:
>
> - `$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential`  # Debian / Ubuntu
> - `% sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel`  # Red Hat / CentOS
>
> Then you can install mysqlclient via pip now:
>
> `$ pip install mysqlclient`